# NLTK can't find the Stanford POS tagger model file

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I am trying to use StanfordPOSTagger from the NLTK. I  downloaded Stanford POS full tagger. I have set

```
CLASSPATH=/home/waheeb/Stanford_Tools/stanford-postagger-full-2015-12-09  /stanford-postagger.jar
STANFORD_MODELS=home/waheeb/Stanford_Tools/stanford-postagger-full-2015-12-09/models
```

When I type the following in python:

```
>>> from nltk.tag import StanfordPOSTagger
>>> st = StanfordPOSTagger('english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger')
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/waheeb/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tag /stanford.py", line 136, in __init__
super(StanfordPOSTagger, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/waheeb/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tag/stanford.py", line 56, in __init__
env_vars=('STANFORD_MODELS',), verbose=verbose)
File "/home/waheeb/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages /nltk/internals.py", line 573, in find_file
file_names, url, verbose))
File "/home/waheeb/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 567, in find_file_iter
raise LookupError('\n\n%s\n%s\n%s' % (div, msg, div))
```

LookupError:

```
=========================================================================
NLTK was unable to find the english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger file!
Use software specific configuration paramaters or set the TANFORD_MODELS  environment variable.
==========================================================================
```

Why is that??

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/alvations/e1df0ba227e542955a8a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use `export` in the command line before calling your python script. I.e.

```
alvas@ubi:~$ export STANFORDTOOLSDIR=$HOME
alvas@ubi:~$ export CLASSPATH=$STANFORDTOOLSDIR/stanford-postagger-full-2015-12-09/stanford-postagger.jar
alvas@ubi:~$ export STANFORD_MODELS=$STANFORDTOOLSDIR/stanford-postagger-full-2015-12-09/models
alvas@ubi:~$ python
```

For more details see https://gist.github.com/alvations/e1df0ba227e542955a8a

---

Similar problems includes:

- [Setting NLTK with Stanford NLP (both StanfordNERTagger and StanfordPOSTagger) for Spanish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037094/setting-nltk-with-stanford-nlp-both-stanfordnertagger-and-stanfordpostagger-fo)
- [Error using Stanford POS Tagger in NLTK Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930328/error-using-stanford-pos-tagger-in-nltk-python)
- [Can't make Stanford POS tagger working in nltk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34692987/cant-make-stanford-pos-tagger-working-in-nltk)
- [trouble importing stanford pos tagger into nltk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344916/trouble-importing-stanford-pos-tagger-into-nltk)
- [Stanford Parser and NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883277/stanford-parser-and-nltk)

Comment: @alvas....I exported them already. I forgot to mention that in the question. But the error is still there.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on https://gist.github.com/alvations/e1df0ba227e542955a8a carefully?

Comment: Perfect ... thanks. If you also notice I forgot to add '/' before home in STANFORD_MODELS=/